# jquery modal-dialog , buttons, redirecting to link, passing php variables in jquery/js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

```
$("#modal_confirmation").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            bgiframe: true,
            resizable: true,
            width:500,
            modal: true,
            overlay: {
                backgroundColor: '#000',
                opacity: 0.5
            },
            buttons: {
                             'Delete': function() {
                            //HERE I HAVE TO PUT A LINK TO GO TO A URL*
                                   $(this).dialog('close');
                             },
                            'Cancel': function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }

            }
        });
```

- The link has to pass php variables. I've tried something like: 
  'Delete':

  function() {
  window.location = "delete_content?id=" $idC

and also

```
window.location = "delete_content?id=" <?php echo $idC;?>



 <a  class='btn_no_text btn ui-state-default ui-corner-all tooltip modal_confirmation_link'  title='Eliminar' href=''>
      <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close'></span>
     </a>
```

When you click on that link it opens a model-dialong with the buttons that I show above. So summing up when u click on delete it should go to a link that looks something like:

```
delete_content.php?id=SOME NUMBER.
```

I've also tried to acess the href attribute on the html/php but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
buttons: {
     'Delete': function() {
     **var linkToRedirect = document.getElementById('completeLink').value;
     window.location = linkToRedirect;**
     $(this).dialog('close');
},
```

And on the form:

`<input type='hidden' name='completeLink'  id='completeLink'` `value='delete_content.php?&id=$idC' />`